# Trying to write a sql which can give the expected ouput

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image][image]I have one source table and one target table. If minus of 2 column is positive then need to insert the record until the minus become negative. I am sharing the input and expected output.

Expecting the records should inserted until its minus of column of source table (a-d) become negative.

Comment: Please read : [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the `lag` window function and inner queries as follows:

```
-- input data
with your_table as(
select 7256 a, 1 b, 1 c, 256 d from dual union all
select 14632, 2, 2, 1052 from dual union all
select 22428, 3, 3, 1428 from dual union all
select 29864, 4, 4, 1864 from dual union all
select 36472, 5, 5, 8864 from dual union all
select 44699, 6, 6, 15472 from dual union all
select 51467, 7, 7, 16840 from dual union all
select 53067, 8, 8, 23840 from dual union all
select 60371, 9, 9, 25067 from dual union all
select 66171, 10, 10, 32067 from dual
)
-- Actual query
select t.a, t.b, tt.c, tt.d, t.a-tt.d as diff from
(select a,b,c,d, COALESCE(lag(a) over (order by a), 0) lag_a
from your_table t) t join
(select a,b,c,d, COALESCE(lag(d) over (order by d), 0) lag_d
from your_table t) tt
on t.a > tt.lag_d and TT.D > T.LAG_A
order by t.a, tt.d
```

Output:

```
         A          B          C          D       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7256          1          1        256       7000
      7256          1          2       1052       6204
      7256          1          3       1428       5828
      7256          1          4       1864       5392
      7256          1          5       8864      -1608
     14632          2          5       8864       5768
     14632          2          6      15472       -840
     22428          3          6      15472       6956
     22428          3          7      16840       5588
     22428          3          8      23840      -1412
     29864          4          8      23840       6024
     29864          4          9      25067       4797
     29864          4         10      32067      -2203
     36472          5         10      32067       4405

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: now its failing for other set of input:
Innput  
a b c d 
5 1 0 500 
6 1 0 4104 
972 1 0 972 
1002 1 0 1002 
1008 1 0 1008 
1008 1 0 1008 
2184 1 0 4380 
2292 1 0 2292 
2500 1 0 2500 
3115 1 0 10615 
3186 1 0 3186 
7500 1 0 10900 

Expected output

a b c d a-d
5 1 1 500 -495
6 1 1 4104 -4098
7 2 1 500 -493
500 3 1 500 
1002 1 1 1002 
1008 1 1 1008 
1008 1 1 1008 
2184 1 1 4380 -2196
2292 1 1 2292 
2500 1 1 2500 
3115 1 1 10615 -7500
3186 1 1 3186 
4104 2 1 4104 
4380 2 1 4380 
7500 1 1 10900 -3400
8115 2 1 10615 -2500
10615 3 1 10615 
10900 2 1 10900